# My PC peripherals keeps restarting internally while gaming

Tags: windows

I have recently got myself a fairly high-end PC and I am facing a really unique issue sometimes, It's a little complicated to explain but I will try.  All my peripherals (Bluetooth mouse/keyboard,  wifi) suddenly disconnect or more like restart quickly while the system is still running and can continue as normal. Happens mostly while gaming. Since the mouse and keyboard are on Bluetooth, it takes a bit to connect again, same with the wifi. I can see that all my fan's RGB also flicker at the same time as if it was a quick restart internally. Please note nothing happens with the running programs, monitor, or anything it's still running.  If I restart the system, the problem doesn't occur for some time.

This is really sad as I don't even know how to search for the issue. Any help will be highly appreciated. :(

Comment: Run the manufacturer's Driver Update App including BIOS (UEFI) and update all drivers and see if that helps.

Comment: Thanks John, I will give it a try.

Comment: Please let us know if the updates work

Comment: There was indeed an update available for the bios. Did that and haven't faced the issue yet. Looks like that was the problem indeed. Thank you so much! Cheers

Comment: I posted an answer for you and I trust you will acknowledge it.

Answer (score 0):

> My PC peripherals keeps restarting internally while gaming

Based on your description, Run the manufacturer's Driver Update App including BIOS (UEFI) and update all drivers and see if that helps.

Note:   In a comment you have said that updating BIOS fixed the issue, so that was the problem.